# How to tune the render of COLLADA files in Gazebo?

Tags: collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

I have build a robot model for the youBot from COLLADA files provided by KUKA. I would say that everything is fine, but I am somehow disappointing by the display of the robot parts (see screenshots bellow).

I don't know anything about 3D so I do not have the word to tell precisely the problem. I would say that the colors are too bright, preventing to see the shape of the parts. Moreover, this feeling is not consistent between Gazebo and rviz. Only the orange of the arm in Gazebo is fine. The black and the grey do not let the user to imagine the edges.

I had a look at the COLLADA files but did not notice anything. They contains tags for black, orange and grey. I have checked the parts in meshlab. The meshes are fine. Unfortunately meshlab does not read the color. The files can be found in this repo:

```
https://github.com/Arn-O/youbot_ros_tools
```

The wheels have been simulated with simple spheres and the display is fine too.

So, is there any way to improve this? I would say ideally without modify the COLLADA files. Maybe the light is not correct (I use the standard world file).

Thanks for your answers!

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4536/how-to-tune-the-render-of-collada-files-in-gazebo?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try opening your collada files, and look for "ambient", "diffuse", and "emission" properties. Adjust the values up to make the model brighter.

A better, but more complicated approach, is to texture wrap each mesh. You'll need to use a tool like Blender, Maya, or 3ds max to accomplish this. There are plenty of tutorials on line.

It's also possible that the normals for your mesh are incorrect. You can check them in a 3d editor (blender, for example).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1